# OS.File to figure out if user typed just a folder name or absolute path

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to use OS.File to detect if user typed an absolute path, or just a folder name.

I'm using OS.File.split and looking for the `absolute` attribute. However for windows it returns true for absolute even for something like this `\\blah\\rawr` so what Im doing is checking for drive.

Is this a good cross platform/os way to test if its absolute or just a folder path?

```
var tp = '\\rawr\\rawr\\my new profile' //var typedPath
var tpSplit = OS.Path.split(tp); //var typedPathSplit
console.info('tpSplit:', tpSplit);
var IsAbsolute = 'winIsAbsolute' in OS.Path ? tpSplit.winDrive ? true : false : tpSplit.absolute;
```

This is for creating a new profile. If user just types a name, then its a relative profile, if user types an absolute path than its a non-relative profile so I do `OS.File.makeDir(tp, {from:tpSplit.components[0]})` to make the directory. (I'm hoping `{from:tpSplit.components[0]}` doesn't cause problems on linux as in linux components[0] is blank like `/home/desktop/new folder`
)

Answer (score 1):

Unix absolute paths begin with `/`

```js
function isAbsolute(path){
  if("winIsAbsolute" in OS.Path){
    return OS.Path.winIsAbsolute(path);
  }
  else{
    return path[0] == "/";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man yeah I noted that in the question. It's a problem because if user types that, and i say `from:tpSplit.components[0]` `makeDir` fails.

Comment: @Noitidart then your question is not how to find if a path is absolute or not  (I edited my answer for the sake of clarity)

Comment: For the the else part can't we just rely on `path.absolute`

Comment: For windows, is it possible to be an absolute path even if the path does not start with a drive? Because that's how im detecting absolute paths right now, if there is a drive.

Comment: It is possible, if the path is pointing to a network location. But seriously, why would the user setup a Firefox profile there?